# Macro-enabled workbook saved to wrong folder

Tags: excel, vba, path, save, directory

When I use the following code to:

1. save a macro-enabled workbook
2. in the same folder as the open workbook

it does save the file with the wrong name and on the desktop:

```
Sub Save_New_MacroEnabledFile()

    Dim thisWb As Workbook

    Set thisWb = ActiveWorkbook
    Worksheets("Sheet_with_VBA_Button").Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=thisWb.Path & Sheets("Sheet_with_NewFile's_Name").Range("A2"), FileFormat:= _
        xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, Password:=vbNullString, WriteResPassword:=vbNullString, _
        ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False

End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't add slash when you creating new filepath.

Probably the folder where you have this file is on the desktop and without slash it just append the name of the file to the name of the folder, i.e.
folder was:

```
C:\Users\Antoine\Desktop\Folder
```

and after appending the filename without slash it was like:

```
C:\Users\Antoine\Desktop\Folderfilename.xlsx
```

---

Try this code:

```
Sub Save_New_MacroEnabledFile()
    Dim thisWb As Workbook
    Dim fileName As String

    Set thisWb = ActiveWorkbook
    Worksheets("Sheet_with_VBA_Button").Activate

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    fileName = thisWb.Path & "\" & Sheets("Sheet_with_NewFile's_Name").Range("A2") & VBA.IIf(Right(fileName, 5) = ".xlsm", "", ".xlsm")

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=fileName, _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, Password:=vbNullString, WriteResPassword:=vbNullString, _
        ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: that worked! thank you so much!!

What does the "& VBA.IIf(Right(fileName, 5) = ".xlsm", "", ".xlsm")" do?

Comment: It added file extension ".xlsm" if you didn't include it in the filename in the cell A2.

Comment: Understood. Very handy. Thank you Mielk!